# Using automapper to update entities with relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core and Automapper to update my entities. I have an entity called "Aluno", which has a relationship to "Endereco". Here is the code:

```
public class Aluno : ApplicationUser{

    ...
    public Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class AlunoViewModel : UserViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public EnderecoViewModel Endereco { get; set; }
}

public class Endereco{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get;set; }

   ...
}

public class EnderecoViewModel {

    public int Id { get;set; }
    ...
}
```

The automapper configuration:

```
config.CreateMap<Aluno, AlunoViewModel>().ReverseMap();
config.CreateMap<Endereco, EnderecoViewModel>().ReverseMap();
```

AlunosController:

```
[HttpPut]
    public JsonResult Put([FromBody]AlunoViewModel vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var aluno = _context.Alunos
                .Single(o => o.Id == vm.Id);

            Mapper.Map(vm, aluno);

            _context.SaveChanges();

            Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
            return Json(true);
        }

        Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return Json(false);
    }
```

When I try to update an "Aluno" entity, I'm getting an exception on context.SaveChanges():

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Enderecos'
>   when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

But i'm not trying to insert a new "Endereco", just update the entity "Aluno", and maybe update the "Endereco", which is loaded correctly inside the var aluno.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think you have mapping problem. Please check your mappings are correct before save operation. Your Aluno mapping needs that "ForMember" function to define mapping for its property objects. Can you try to add ForMember(i => i.Endereco, i => i.MapFrom(s =>s.Endereco)).

Comment: You are right! Could you post it as an answer so I can mark it? Thank you!

Comment: @Munir: Please don't abuse AutoMapper to bind back to entities, this will get you in big trouble, especially when mapping back collections. AutoMapper is and was never intended for two way mappings. Please read the AutoMapper author's post here https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/18/the-case-for-two-way-mapping-in-automapper/ on the use cases for which AutoMapper was intended and works fine. Trying to abuse it for two way binding results in a) your domain models breaking encapuslation to support that and b) your persistence model/ORM Mapper having issues with the bindings.

Comment: See this blog post to understand why using AutoMapper with ORM (ViewModel to Persistence Model binding) is bad and evil and will cause you nightmares writing your code http://rogerjohansson.blog/2013/12/01/why-mapping-dtos-to-entities-using-automapper-and-entityframework-is-horrible/ It may work well if you use it the other way (Persistence Model -> dto or viewmodel, but also may bring you in trouble by triggering lazy loading, which happens in sync, so blocking your ASP.NET request thread from being returned to the thread pool)

Comment: @Tseng, I agree with you. I solved the problem above but i'm getting lot of other problems now, related to Automapper. I decided to map properties directly from ViewModel to Entity, when doing inserts or updates. Thank you for the references, were very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following syntax:

```
Mapper
    .CreateMap<Aluno, AlunoViewModel>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.Endereco,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EnderecoViewModel)
    );
```

Comment: Sorry, need to downvote. While it may solve the immediate issue, you are just encouraging the OP and others to use AutoMapper in the wrong way. AutoMapper is not intended to be used in two way bindings to domain models or persistence model! https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/18/the-case-for-two-way-mapping-in-automapper/

Comment: I am not encouraging anyone to use any specific way of doing anything, just showed how AutoMapper should be used if they are using it, no need to downvote @Tseng

Comment: @Tseng, although your point is almost right, I don't think is fair to downvote the answer. It solves the problem and downvoting will not help other people. What would really help would be to post an answer with the solution that you find most appropriate.